# Changing the name of a picture makes the picture looks small

Tags: image, cocoa-touch, ios5

I have a picture. I call it Publictransportation.

It looks smaller than it should be. It looks fine on simulator. But it looks small on iPhone.

I clean build. Delete the application. No luck.

Then I change the pic to Publictransportation1

Now it looks normal.

When I change back it looks small again.

There has to be some false cache. But where?

Comment: This is probably an issue which involves the device being a retina device (iPhone 4 to 5), while the simulator being non-retina.

Comment: But how come changing the name of the file works>?

Comment: When you change the pic to `Publictransportation1` are you changing both the file name of the image file and the name that it gets loaded by? It would be good for you to show some code.

Comment: And I also tested this on retina simulator

Comment: You'll need to show some code so we can get a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the app from your device and using Product -> Clean on Xcode?

Comment: Also, it would be good to show a screenshot of what you mean by 'smaller'.

Answer (score 0):

May be there are two images like one Publictransportation.png present in resources and another one will be just reference of Publictransportation.png, which might me there on your machine.

Search Publictransportation.png in your project and check for duplication.

Comment: did that there is no duplicate. Both are references.

Comment: So are you telling that there are two reference of "Publictransportation.png"?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are using the device that has retina display, so you need to rename your picture with @2x in the end in order for the retina to take it as a double size, and from time to time try to clean your project an rebuild it again.